# Python/SWIG: Output an array

Tags: python, return-value, swig

I am trying to output an array of values from a C function wrapped using SWIG for Python. The way I am trying to do is using the following typemap.

Pseudo code:

```
int oldmain() {
float *output = {0,1};
return output;
}
```

Typemap:

```
%typemap(out) float* { 
   int i; 
  $result = PyList_New($1_dim0); 
   for (i = 0; i < $1_dim0; i++) { 
 PyObject *o = PyFloat_FromDouble((double) $1[i]); 
 PyList_SetItem($result,i,o); 
 } 
}
```

My code compiles well, but it hangs when I run access this function (with no more ways to debug it).

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your Makefile or similar?  You might find Cython easier than SWIG, unless you might do more languages than just Python.

Comment: Thanks, Oleksiy's answer solved my issue, but as you said, Cython seems to be easier and I am exploring that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
/* example.c */

float * oldmain() {
    static float output[] = {0.,1.};
    return output;
}
```

You are returning a pointer here, and swig has no idea about the size of it. Plain $1_dim0 would not work, so you would have to hard code or do some other magic. Something like this:

```
/* example.i */
%module example
%{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
  extern float * oldmain();
%}

%typemap(out) float* oldmain {
  int i;
  //$1, $1_dim0, $1_dim1
  $result = PyList_New(2);
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PyFloat_FromDouble((double) $1[i]);
    PyList_SetItem($result,i,o);
  }
}

%include "example.c"
```

Then in python you should get:

```
>> import example
>> example.oldmain()
[0.0, 1.0]
```

When adding typemaps you may find `-debug-tmsearch` very handy, i.e.

```
swig -python -debug-tmsearch example.i
```

Should clearly indicate that your typemap is used when looking for a suitable 'out' typemap for `float *oldmain`. Also if you just like to access c global variable array you can do the same trick using typemap for `varout` instead of just `out`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. This worked well. I am trying to generalize this for any length of array, so I am using $1_dim0 instead of "2" and I encounter this issue (also found in the documentation http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn39)
. example_wrap.c:2979: error: ‘result_dim0’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @seu - you can't do that because the size of the array isn't known. The return type is `float*`, not `float[2]` which is needed for the `$1_dim0` thing to work.

Comment: @Flexo. Thanks. I tried to use "%typemap(out) float [ANY] {" as in the documentation and it compiles, but in Python the return value I get is <Swig Object of type 'float *' at 0x9175470> .  Essentially I am trying to return an array with variable length. Is there a way to do this, or do I always have to know the length?

Comment: +1 for the -debug-tmsearch; I had a similar problem and the debugging output helped me to figure out that I actually want to write an 'argout' typemap and not 'out' typemap

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to allow the length to vary is to add another output parameter that tells you the size of the array too:

```
%module test

%include <stdint.i>

%typemap(in,numinputs=0,noblock=1) size_t *len  {
  size_t templen;
  $1 = &templen;
}

%typemap(out) float* oldmain {
  int i;
  $result = PyList_New(templen);
  for (i = 0; i < templen; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PyFloat_FromDouble((double)$1[i]);
    PyList_SetItem($result,i,o);
  }
}

%inline %{
float *oldmain(size_t *len) {
  static float output[] = {0.f, 1.f, 2, 3, 4};
  *len = sizeof output/sizeof *output;
  return output;
}
%}
```

This is modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680521/168175%5D) to add `size_t *len` which can be used to return the length of the array at run time. The typemap completely hides that output from the Python wrapper though and instead uses it in the `%typemap(out)` instead of a fixed size to control the length of the returned list.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'll try this. Another question: If I have a variable or a #define constant in my C code, which is my output  array length, is there a way I could use this instead of "templen" in your example?

Comment: @seu - the easiest way is just to stick it inside the out typemap for the call to `PyList_New` and the `for` loop.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: I tried define a constant inside my c file and I get the following errors `example_wrap.c:2980: error: ‘ARRLENGTH’ undeclared (first use in this function)` . My intent is to not declare this again but somehow be able to access this variable/constant.

Comment: @SEU - you'll need to do `%{ #include "whatever.h" %}` *before* the typemap to make the definition of `ARRLENGTH` visible in the generated wrapper.