# return double * from swig as python list

Tags: c++, python, pointers, swig

I have a C++ class, one of whose methods returns a `double *` array-like that is one of its member variables. I'm trying to make this accessible as a list in Python. I wrap it in a `doubleArray_frompointer`, and then try using deepcopy to get it out of there safely, but I still have problems when the `doubleArray` goes out of scope, its memory is cleaned up, and then the C++ class tries to clean up the same memory (although that's not shown in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/4349180) I created).

I suspect I should be doing this with typemaps.

What I'm trying to wrap is:

```
double *foo() {
  double *toReturn = new double[2];
  toReturn[0] = 2;
  toReturn[1] = 4;
  return toReturn;
}
```

and the interface is:

```
%module returnList
%include "returnList.h"

%include "cpointer.i"
%pointer_functions(double, doubleP)

%include "carrays.i"
%array_class(double, doubleArray);

%{
#include "returnList.h"
%}
```

Comment: "Typemaps are generally not a required part of using SWIG." Maybe I'm missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in saying that a typemap can be used to avoid writing a loop on the Python side. I put together an example - it's pretty similar to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680521/168175).

```
%module test

%typemap(out) double *foo %{
  $result = PyList_New(2); // use however you know the size here
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    PyList_SetItem($result, i, PyFloat_FromDouble($1[i]));
  }
  delete $1; // Important to avoid a leak since you called new
%}

%inline %{
double *foo() {
  double *toReturn = new double[2];
  toReturn[0] = 2;
  toReturn[1] = 4;
  return toReturn;
}
%}
```

The typemap here matches a function called `foo` returning `double *` - you could match more widely but then there would be a risk of doing the wrong thing for functions where returning `double *` doesn't mean you're returning an array of size 2.

With this typemap I can then run:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.foo()
[2.0, 4.0]
>>>
```

The reason you need to write it manually like this is because there is no way for SWIG to infer the length of the array that you are returning from `foo`. It could even vary between calls.

Comment: It will vary between calls, but that length `numRounds` is one of the program parameters. That is, it _is_ a variable we have accessible in Python (on the order of ~200). Does this mean I _should_ use a loop in Python? But, somehow, I still have to write `new` in the swig interface file, or in my C++ code, so that Python and the C++ class both don't try to clean up the same memory.

Comment: The [gist](https://gist.github.com/4349180) was an oversimplification. I'm returning a class member, not just from a function. Fixed now, but it doesn't give the errors I was hoping it would.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for the question as asked. However, I really should have been using a std::vector<double> instead of a double * array instead, since SWIG automatically wraps these as tuples if you include std_vector, so it's iterable and the length is known. I've changed the gist to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I 'solved' the problem not by returning any sort of vector- or array-like object, but instead by recreating in Python the (simple) loop that generated the array in the first place. That is, my C++ code only has to return individual doubles, and my Python code will assemble the list.

To be slighly more explicit, I have the C++ method `double *simulation.run()`, that was causing trouble. I created a new C++ method `double simulation.doRound()`, and then called this via SWIG in a Python loop of `numRounds` iterations, doing `outputs.append(simulation.doRound())` each iteration.

However, I would still like to know how to copy a C/C++ `double *` array to a Python list via SWIG, since this seems like such a basic operation. If someone could answer that, I'd mark such as the accepted answer.