# How to convert a C++ array to a Python list using SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, list, swig

I am trying to write a piece of code in C++ which can produce an array and return it as as a Python list. I understand that I can return the list as a NumPy array using the typemaps in numpy.i instead, but NumPy is not installed on some of the clusters I am using. The main difference between this question and some similar ones I've seen on here is that I want to return a C array of variable length as a Python list.

The stripped down C++ routine is below:

```
/* File get_rand_list.cpp */
#include "get_rand_list.h"

/* Define function implementation */ 
double* get_rand_list(int length) {

  output_list = new double[length];

  /* Populate input NumPy array with random numbers */
  for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
    output_list[i] = ((double) rand()) / RAND_MAX;

  return output_list;
}
```

I would like to be able to use this in Python as so:

```
from get_rand_list import *
list = get_rand_list(10)
```

Which would return a Python list of 10 random floats. How can I use SWIG typemaps to wrap the C++ routine to do this? If there is a simpler way which requires some small modifications to the C++ routine that is most likely fine.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using C++ it is easiest to use STL: SWIG knows how to convert std::vector to Python list, so use

```
std::vector<double> get_rand_list(int length) { ... }
```

Don't forget to %import std_vector.i. This trick is very useful in general, see the [Library section of SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_stl_cpp_library) for other typemaps pre-written. Always favor pre-written typemaps over making your own.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered several times already

[return double * from swig as python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033387/return-double-from-swig-as-python-list)

[SWIG C-to-Python Int Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778500/swig-c-to-python-int-array)

Comment: But the current answers only work for a set array size. I'm interested in variable length arrays.