# Accessing a int16 array using numpy.i and swig

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

The following from c structure has been wrapped with swig so that I can access the data, acquired from another swig wrapped program, in python.

```
struct RadarParm {
  struct {
    char major;
    char minor;
  } revision;

  struct {
   char code;
   char *time;
   char *command;
  } origin;

  int16 cp;
  int16 stid;
  int16 *pulse;
  int16 *lag[2]; 
  char *combf;
};
```

My main issue is with int16 *lag[2]. When trying to read the data in my python code with:

```
p_data['lag'] = prm.lag
```

Where prm is of the type RadarParm returned from the rtserver.c file thru the method struct RadarParm* getRadarParm() and p_data is a python dictionary that stores every part of RadarParm.

Here is my current output when accessing prm.lag:

```
<Swig Object of type 'int16 **' at 0x1fd55d0>
```

I have found that there seems to be a numpy.i file that handles arrays and int16 data types. From my limited understanding I would think that this would allow me to access this data. If I could implement it correctly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%apply (int16** ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1, DIM_TYPE* DIM1) {(int16* lag,2)};
```

When compiling this I get:

```
Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance numpy.i did not work. The main problem was numpy.i does not support *(out)* typemaps which in this case was precisely what I needed.

Instead using the command -debug-tmsearch when compiling the swig rtserver.i file. Using the output from the command I was able to determine the defined swig type for RadarParm::lag and what it should be. Here is the code that works.

```
%typemap(out) int16*[2] {
  int i;
  $result = PyList_New(2);
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PyInt_FromLong($1[i]);
    PyList_SetItem($result,i,o);
  }
}
%apply int16*{lag[2]};
```

Most of this was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679023/python-swig-output-an-array/11680521#11680521)