# SWIG "out" typemap returns address instead of data

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am using SWIG to accept a list that is variable in size from Python, send it to C++ to do something with it, and then send it back to Python to be printed out.

I am new to Python, C++ and Swig. Currently the sent list will be handled as a vector argument in my C++ function. After that what is returned from the function is a pointer, which is handled by an "out" typemap.

The list is able to be shown from Python, however only if given a set size in the out typemap. Currently I need to make it handle lists of various sizes.

When trying to achieve this, I end up returning the address rather than a list in Python.

Below showcases the code that works when given a fixed size.

customvector.cc

```
#include "customvector.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

float * summy(std::vector<float> a)
{
    float * p = a.data();
    return p;
}
```

customvector.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

float * summy(std::vector<float> a);
```

customvector.i

```
/* File: customvector.i */
%module customvector

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "customvector.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%include <stdint.i>

namespace std {
%template(Line) vector < float >;

}

%typemap(out) float* summy{ 
  int i;
  $result = PyList_New(3); 
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PyFloat_FromDouble((double) $1[i]);
    PyList_SetItem($result,i,o);
  }
}

float * summy(std::vector<float> a);
```

My python result:

```
>>> import customvector
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> customvector.summy(a)
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

I then edited my interface file so that the out typemap now uses [ANY] instead of just 3 to allow the length to vary.

Edited customvector.i

```
/* File: customvector.i */
%module customvector

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "customvector.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
%include <stdint.i>

namespace std {
%template(Line) vector < float >;

}

%typemap(out) float* summy [ANY]{ //changed from 3 to [ANY]
  int i;
  $result = PyList_New($1_dim0);  //changed from 3 to $1_dim0
  for (i = 0; i < $1_dim0; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PyFloat_FromDouble((double) $1[i]);
    PyList_SetItem($result,i,o);
  }
}

float * summy(std::vector<float> a);
```

Result from Python:

```
>>> import customvector
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> customvector.summy(a)
<Swig Object of type 'float *' at 0x000001E4E32E6420>
```

Which is not what I want, and it should display what was shown earlier on.

I tried following the documentation listed somewhere here: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn40 for SWIG to get the value than the output, but it doesn't seem to work.

I also came across this solution to allow length to vary: [Python/SWIG: Output an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679023/python-swig-output-an-array)
but I am not sure how it works as I tried using it but the code doesn't compile (saying that templen is not defined).

How can I output from C++ into python such a data with variable size?

Comment: Since your function takes a vector by value you have undefined behaviour when you try and use the pointer you return. You also need to have a way for callers of the function to know how big the array actually is.

Comment: Anyway the [ANY] typemap isn't the right choice here because the size isn't know at compile time so isn't getting applied.

Comment: Does that mean I would need to calculate the size of the vector in the cc file then pass it to the interface file to determine how big it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior in your implementation.  Why not use std::vector for the return value as well?

```
%module test

%include <std_vector.i>
%template() std::vector<float>;

%inline %{
std::vector<float> summy(std::vector<float> a)
{
    for(auto& i: a)
        i += 1;
    return a;
}
%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.summy([1,2,3,4])
(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```

The default behavior for returned vectors is to use a tuple.  That can be overridden with a typemap:

```
%module test

%include <std_vector.i>
%template() std::vector<float>;

%typemap(out) std::vector<float> %{
    $result = PyList_New($1.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < $1.size(); ++i)
        PyList_SET_ITEM($result,i,PyFloat_FromDouble($1[i]));
%}

%inline %{
#include <vector>
std::vector<float> summy(std::vector<float> a)
{
    for(auto& i: a)
        i += 1;
    return a;
}
%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.summy([1,2,3,4])
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! There's a reason for that (though perhaps it could be avoided but I have yet to find a solution or am not experienced much with c++). 

I'm using Tensorflow for this, and apparently during compilation returning a vector causes the compilation to fail. Hence I am trying to avoid using vectors for output (slowly testing, if the input for vectors work I would leave it as it is). 

Currently it is recommended to me to try and return this value by reference or by pointer. I'm new to C++ and am now researching how to do so.